# How to move the drawer icon and header to the left of the toolbar

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vuetify.js

My toolbar left a gaping space in its leftmost part, making the toolbar look awkward positioning-wise:

[image: screenshot]

How do I get rid of the space on the left of the icon?

Here's my template:

```html
<v-toolbar app :fixed="toolbar.fixed" :clipped-left="toolbar.clippedLeft" color="black">
  <v-toolbar-side-icon class= "white--text" @click.stop="toggleMiniDrawer"></v-toolbar-side-icon>
  <v-toolbar-title class="text-uppercase white--text">
    <span>
      <v-btn flat class="font-weight-black display-1 white--text" to="/dashboard_so">
    Activities</v-btn>
    </span>
  </v-toolbar-title>
</v-toolbar>

<v-navigation-drawer :clipped="$vuetify.breakpoint.width > 1264" :fixed="drawer.fixed" :permanent="drawer.permanent" :mini-variant="drawer.mini" v-model="drawer.open"
      app class="yellow darken-3"> 
 <v-layout column align-center>    
 </v-layout>
```

Comment: Is this a child of a `v-container` tag? If so, add the fluid attribute. Otherwise use the inspector tool in your browser to find out which element applies the margin. The code you've provided is insufficient.

Comment: Using the inspector tool helped me find the problem, which is in the javascript. I've set toolbar: { clippedLeft: True } and now it's working. Thank you !!